# Question about mapping of elements from $GF(2^8)$ to $GF((2^4)^2)?$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

I understand how to map elements from the $GF(2^8)$ to $GF(((2^2)^2)^2).$

And the isomorphic mapping matrix is
[isomorphic mapping matrix1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3XTp.png)

But recently,I'm reading a paper,and finding something really confusing me.

The paper maps $GF(2^8)$ to $GF((2^4)^2)$ , represents $GF(2^4)$ elements in a Normal basis {$β^4, β^3, β^2, β^1$}, and the modular polynomial for the extension is $α^2 + (β^4 + β)α + β.$

And the result mapping matrix is [isomorphic mapping matrix2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kETWg.png)

Could someone help me how I construct this mapping matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $2^8=(2^4)^2$? What does the notation mean?

Comment: It means we map Galois field $GF(2^8)$ to its subfield $GF((2^4)^2)$ ,because we can use less cost to construct $GF((2^4))$ multiplication and inversion in circuit design.

Comment: Too much is missing for me to trace back the meaning of those mapping matrices. I can guess what $\beta$ is but even then different choices lead to different values of $\beta^4+\beta$ and $\beta$, further leading to different $\alpha$s.

Comment: @KentaS I don't know much at all about the variations, but the idea is to implement the arithmetic of $GF(2^8)$ on a chip with very limited resources (e.g. no memory for look-up-tables). The notation $GF((2^4)^2)$ is used when $GF(256)$ is seen as a 2-dimensional space over $GF(16)$. If they further implement $GF(16)$ arithmetic using two coordinates from $GF(4)$, then they denote it $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ instead. Division/inversion is particularly nasty to implement.

Comment: Those mapping matrices undoubtedly stand for simple change of bases matrices. But the 8 basis elements can be written in $8!=40320$ distinct orders (true, most don't make sense, because obviously a basis for an extension tower is gotten by using the familiar products of basis elements). Anyway, too many choices to figure it all out.

Comment: Study [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167468/11619). The information there may be a bit outdated. I attempt to explain the underlying algebra, but undoubtedly there is more to the optimization. See also rcgldr's answer for they seem to understand the goals of these optimizations better than I do. Anyway, without links to the source such as those given by acapola in that thread nobody can even attempt to answer.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that paper or at least post links to more images of key points in that paper. Mapping via a normal basis is more complicated than mapping via a polynomial basis. This is because what is an irreducible polynomial in $GF((2^4)^2)$, is used as a polynomial in $GF(2^8)$  where it has roots. A brute force search is done for a root W such that in $GF(2^8)$, $(W)+(W^2) = β^4 + β$, and $(W)(W^2) =  β$. An element of $GF((2^4)^2)$, is then $b1 \ W^2 + b0 \ W$.

Comment: Assuming the matrix maps from $GF((2^4)^2)$ to $GF(2^8)$, and that the primitive element of $GF(2^8) = 0x02$, the inverse of that matrix implies that the primitive element of $GF((2^4)^2) = 0xf0 =  1111  \ W^2 + 0000 \ W$. The unknowns are $GF(2^8)$, $GF((2^4)^2)$, β, and W.  More information is needed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - the OP is asking about normal basis mapping. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4647432/327047) for $GF(2^8)$ to $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3757599/327047) for $GF(2^4)$ to $GF((2^2)^2$. My two prior comments explain some of this.